# Laravel One to One with Pivot table

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have read many posts about this, but I still can't figure out how to handle this case, I have 2 tables and a view:

- **Products**: List of products (a catalog table)
- **Customer**: A list of customers
- **Rank**: a dynamic view indicating the top products ordered by the customer in the last 20 days

What is the proper way of representing this in Laravel Eloquent ?

Not that the Rank isn't stored in the catalog as the catalog is cross user.

What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
// retrieve a list of all customer products with their ranking if available
Customer->with('products')->get();
```

For relationships I have:

- Customer < one2many > Product
- Product < one2many > Rank (but one2one per user)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
Customer->with('products.ranks')->get();
```

Laravel allows for relationship chaining.

if that doesn't work maybe something like this...

```
 Customer->with('products.ranks')->where('customer_id',$id)->get();
```